# CSS Input Outline Not Being Removed

Tags: html, css, input, focus

I'm running into an issue where the default blue outline when input fields are focused is not being removed despite trying two CSS techniques to remove the outline. I have tried to use `input:focus` and `input[type="text"]:focus`, but neither are removing this outline. What am I possibly doing wrong with my CSS?

Here is my form with the `comment-box` input:

```
<div class="comment-form">
    <form action="/app/blog/{{this.blogId}}/comment" method="post">
        <label for="data-comment">Comment:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="comment" class="comment-box">
        <button type="submit" class="comment-submit">Comment</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS (`input.comment-box` CSS is working):

```
input.comment-box {
    width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #D8D8D8;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.comment-box input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #D8D8D8;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your code. I would suggest going to inspector and selecting the element. Then click on the right next tot element.style and try again. If this does not work it should be futile to right click the element and go to copy->selector. Select the element and find out under the styles tab what is giving the focus text block the blue outline, it must be something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.comment-box input:focus` means an input box inside the `.comment-box` class, i.e.,

```
<div class="comment-box">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

What you probably want is:

```
input.comment-box:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

or just

```
.comment-box:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the selector `.comment-box input:focus`. That will target `input:focus` inside of `.comment-box`, which doesn't exist.

The selector either needs to be `.comment-box:focus` or `input:focus` or `.comment-form input:focus`

Answer (score 0):

For this case, input should always come first > class/id > pseudo-class.

```
input.comment-box:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Otherwise

```
.comment-form input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you why it's not working in this case, but I will suggest that you think carefully and read http://www.outlinenone.com/ before you actually remove the outline.  It exists so that someone who is not using a mouse can navigate among form inputs and determine which one has focus.  It appears that your styles will remove ANY distinction between the focused and unfocused input box.  Essentially, this means you are excluding numerous people with disabilities from using your website.